# Is there a way to share Dockerfile operations across a monorepo

Tags: docker, docker-compose, service, monorepo

So I've got a application that consists of lets say 4 APIs and a Frontend, all saved on a monorepo.
Everything is setup with docker, every Service has its own Dockerfile.
The file structure would look something like this:

```
project
│   README.md
│   docker-compose.yml
│
└───api1
│   │   src
|   |   ...
│   │   Dockerfile
│   
└───api2
│   │   src
│   │   ...
│   │   Dockerfile
│   
└───api3
|   │   src
|   │   ...
...
```

And everything works fine. An APIs Dockerfile would look something like this:

```
FROM some_image as deployment
EXPOSE xxxx/tcp

COPY ...

RUN apk add --no-cache curl~7.80 ...

...

CMD [...]
```

Now I would have something like curl~7.80 aswell as other packages that would be needed in api 1-3. 
My question is, is there some way to share  this package and/or this whole RUN operation across my services in a way so that i can modify this in one place instead?

For instance, if there happens to be a hypothetical vulnerability in curl~7.80 that gets fixed in 7.90, I want to be able to modify the version in one place instead of going through all folders and all Dockerfiles to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some way to share this package and/or this whole RUN operation across my services in a way so that I can modify this in one place instead?

Yes, you can achieve this by structuring your project as follows:

```
project
│   README.md
│   docker-compose.yml
│
└───api1
│   │   src
│   │    ...
│   │   Dockerfile
│   
└───...
│
│
│
│___common/
    │   dependencies.txt
```

in the `common` folder, you can then place a text file which lists the dependencies (or a shell script directly), and you can then use that in the Dockerfiles:

```
FROM some_image as deployment
EXPOSE xxxx/tcp

COPY common/dependencies.txt .
RUN apk add `cat dependencies.txt`
...
```

where `project/common/dependencies.txt` contains:

```
curl~7.80
```

---

**Note:** this will obviously imply that the Dockerfiles will require to be built from the `project` directory, e.g.:

```
docker build -f api1/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Isnt NX for this more suitable?

Comment: @mrRobot whats NX?

Comment: Nx is a smart, fast and extensible build system with first class monorepo support and powerful integrations. https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro

Comment: @mrRobot never heard of it. add your own answer